# Get Picture from Facebook Post URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to get picture url from facebook post url

Eg:
http://www.facebook.com/358611630900842/posts/487616328000371

Any way i could get it using app id and secret instead of access token?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The URL below

```
https://graph.facebook.com/358611630900842_511678198927517?fields=picture&access_token={access_token}
```

Will return the JSON:

```
{
  "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1450112_509944245767579_303299763_s.jpg", 
  "id": "358611630900842_511678198927517", 
  "created_time": "2013-11-22T02:00:01+0000"
}
```

If that data were stored under the variable name "data" you could parse the picture url using:

```
var url = data.picture
```

You do need an access token to make a graph call but if you are trying to avoid burdening your user with permissions you can access lots of public data with an app access token which can be generated via the following php script using the Facebook php sdk:

```
   require 'libs/fb/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => '{app_id}',
      'secret' => '{app_secret}',
    ));

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    echo $access_token;
```

Comment: can we do it with facebook app details instead of access_token?